# Running a function within a service before the DOM is loaded in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular site where I load the brand in dynamically with a brand code and controls the rest of the functions on the site. If the user clicks anything on the site before this brand has loaded in (i.e. if the connection to the API is slow due to traffics, connection issues etc.), then they progress but the brand is left behind and everything is out of sync.

I load the brand from a service call in app.component.ts:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    // Get the brand for the first time
    this.brandService.getBrand(window.location.origin);
    console.log(new Date().toString(), 'AppComp => this.brandService.getBrand()');
}
```

The call itself is nothing special:

```js
// Get a Brand into cache
getBrand(url: string) {
    this.brandRequest = {
      Url: url,
      BrandLookupType: 'review'
    };
    this.http.post<BrandLookup>(this.api + this.controller + 'getbrandlookup', this.brandRequest).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(new Date().toString(), this.constructor.name, '=> getBrand()', res);
        this.brandLookup = res;
        const bronzeMin = this.brandLookup.pricingMatrix.singleWillPrice;
        const silverMin = this.brandLookup.pricingMatrix.singleWillPrice + this.brandLookup.pricingMatrix.lifetimeInterestPrice;
        const goldMin = this.brandLookup.pricingMatrix.singleDWTPrice;
        localStorage.setItem('brandCode', this.brandLookup.brandCode);
        localStorage.setItem('ssoUrl', this.brandLookup.ssoUrl);
        localStorage.setItem('cpUrl', this.brandLookup.customerPortalUrl);
        localStorage.setItem('reviewUrl', this.brandLookup.reviewUrl);
        localStorage.setItem('brand', JSON.stringify(this.brandLookup.brand));
        // Set Bronze Landing Page price
        if (bronzeMin === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('bronzeMin', '89');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('bronzeMin', bronzeMin.toString());
        }
        // Set Silver Landing Page Price
        if (silverMin === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('silverMin', '239');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('silverMin', silverMin.toString());
        }
        // Set Gold Landing Page Price
        if (goldMin === null) {
            localStorage.setItem('goldMin', '550');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('goldMin', goldMin.toString());
        }
        this.broadcastBrandUpdate();
    });
}
```

I basically need a way to halt the DOM from loading on screen until this call is complete - is there a way to do this in Angular?

Comment: You'd need to return the observable from the service and subscribe to it in the component. Then you could wrap the template in `<ng-container *ngIf=!loading> ... </ng-continer>` and set it to `this.loading = true;`  using the [`finalize()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do two things here -

First of all, let me tell you what I understood from your question - You don't want users to click anywhere until the brands are not loaded that's all.

1. The best solution is to show a full-screen loader until the brand API didn't return the data. Once you have the data hide the loader and let the user click anywhere.
2. Use resolver guard and make your brand API call inside the resolver and the resolver will protect your screen, your screen will not load until the brand API is not successful.

I have added some good resources to learn how to implement the resolver guards into your application.

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/angular-resolver